# Why BERT model have to keep 10% MASK token unchanged?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I am reading BERT model paper. In Masked Language Model task during pre-training BERT model, the paper said the model will choose 15% token ramdomly. In the chose token (Ti), 80% it will be replaced with [MASK] token, 10% Ti is unchanged and 10% Ti replaced with another word. I think the model just need to replace with [MASK] or another word is enough. Why does the model have to choose randomly a word and keep it unchanged? Does pre-training process predict only [MASK] token or it predict 15% a whole random token?

Comment: the paper is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf), and the sentence in question is in 3.1 pretraining BERT Task #1 Masked LM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done because they want to pre-train a bidirectional model. Most of the time the network will see a sentence with a [MASK] token, and its trained to predict the word that is supposed to be there. But in fine-tuning, which is done after pre-training (fine-tuning is the training done by everyone who wants to use BERT on their task), there are no [MASK] tokens! (unless you specifically do masked LM).

This mismatch between pre-training and training (sudden disappearence of the [MASK] token) is softened by them, with a probability of 15% the word is not replaced by [MASK]. The task is still there, the network has to predict the token, but it actually gets the answer already as input. This might seem counterintuitive but makes sense when combined with the [MASK] training.

Comment: I think you're answeing a question of "Why not just use MASK alone, without REPLACED or SAME-WORD?". The question seems to be a bit different: "Why not just use MASK + REPLACED alone, without SAME-WORD?". The answer is that without SAME-WORD, the model will try to avoid using token k input for producing  token k output, since every time it's asked to predict, the token is wrong (either MASK or REPLACED). (The model would fail to completely ignore it; its architecture won't allow that. But it will try.) This may be counter-productive since token k input is quite relevant for token k output.

Comment: @max So BERT wants to use both the context input and the token k input to predict token k output. 80% of the time using [MASK] forces the token k output to be learnt from the context input. Is that right?